# How do I remove a group of rows based on condition met in one in matlab? Have code but not sure what's going wrong?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to detect high amplitude events and remove them along with rows above and below. I have the following code which does this in part but not fully and I'm not sure where the error is. I have commented out the the audioread function and added randi to allow reproducible results. Code:

```
%[data, fs] = audioread("noise.wav");

%t1 = linspace(0, (numel(data)-1)/fs, numel(data));

rng(1)
data = randi(10,1000,1);

threshold = 5;
clear_range = 10; %rows/samples
data = clearRange(data, threshold, clear_range);

%t1 = linspace(0, (numel(data)-1)/fs, numel(data));

%plot(t1, data);

plot(data)

function [data] = clearRange(data, threshold, clear_range, compare_column)
% data: matrix of values to clean
% threshold: value to compare values against
% clear_range: number of rows to delete
% compare_column: column to check for value to compare against threshold
    if nargin < 4
        compare_column = 1;
    end

    for i = 1:length(data)
        if i > length(data)
            break
        end
        if data(i,compare_column) > threshold
            data(max(1, i-clear_range):min(length(data), i+clear_range),:) = [];
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem with your code is that you modify `data` while looping over it. This means, you delete peaks (or high amplitude events in your words) in rows with an index greater than `i`, so that they cannot be taken into account in following iterations.

E.g. consider peaks in rows with indices `4` and `6`, which should cause that rows up to index `16` are removed (with a value of `clear_range equal` to `10`). However, when `i` is equal to `4`, you remove rows up to index `14`. Consequently, you also remove the peak at position `6`, so that it is not taken into account in further iterations.

In general, it is easier to rely on MATLAB's matrix/array operations instead of using loops.
Please find below a possible solution with explanations inline.

```
clc;
% I adjusted inputs to get a minimal example
data            = randi(10,30,1);
threshold       = 9; 
rangeToClear    = 1;
columnToCompare = 1;

dataOut         = clearRange(data, threshold, rangeToClear, columnToCompare );

disp('In:')
disp( data' ); 

disp('Out:')
disp( dataOut' ); % Plot for cross-check


function data = clearRange(data, threshold, rangeToClear, columnToCompare)

% rowsWithPeak is 1-D logical array showing where columnToCompare is greater than the threshold 
rowsWithPeak = data( :, columnToCompare ) > threshold;

% kernel is a column vector of ones of size Nx1, where N is the number of rows 
% that should be removed around a peak
kernel = ones( 2*rangeToClear+1, 1 );

% rowsToRemove is a column vector being greater than one at row indices
% that should be removed from the data. To obtain rowsToRemove, 
% we convolute rowsWithPeak with the kernel. The argument 'same' to 
% the conv2 function, specifies that rowsToRemove will have the same
% size as rowsWithPeak.
rowsToRemove = conv2( rowsWithPeak, kernel, 'same' );

% rowsToRemoveLogical is a logical array being one, where rowsToRemove is greater than 0.
% Note that, rowsToRemoveLogical = rowsToRemove > 0 would also work here
rowsToRemoveLogical = logical( rowsToRemove);

% Finally, we use rowsToRemoveLogical to mask positions of the rows that should be removed.
data( rowsToRemoveLogical, : ) = [];

end
```